# When I put loading into the component, the source code does not appear in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I created a Next Js project. Everything is great. But i have a problem.

I created Home Compoenent with Hooks in /pages/index.js. After, I created isLoading condition for render.

This my code

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Home = () => {

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false)
  }, [])

  return (
    <Fragment>
        {
            isLoading === true ? (
                <div> Loading..</div>
            ): (
                <div>
                    <div>Content</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Again everything is great. But when I look at the source code, nothing appears. Only script tags appear.
Why?

this _app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

How can i solve this ?
Thank you.
Best regards.

Comment: Don't you see `<div> Loading..</div>` when you inspect the page's source?

Comment: i don't see any. only i see script tags

Comment: Do you mind posting a picture of what you're seeing?

Comment: Sure, thats my picture https://i.hizliresim.com/fF9uke.png

Comment: Where is `<div id="myBody" footer-data="1" class="..."></div>` coming from? Can you add the code in your `_app` page to the question as well?

Comment: <div id="myBody" footer-data="1" class="..."></div> this code only layout i see it but i dont see content

Comment: You'll need to post the code for your layout component as well then. The issue is not within the `Home` component, it's further up.

Comment: I shared _app.js

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it seems the useEffect to setState on something that is used on the layout, causes it to only show the js instead of the rendered html. Anyone knows how to resolve this?