# HTML Source code is not visible in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I created Next Js Project. Everything is great but i have a problem. When i use map function for data fetching the html source code is not visible in Next Js

By the way, my user array is not empty.

This my code

```
import useSwr from 'swr'
import Link from 'next/link'

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())

export default function Index() {
  const { data, error } = useSwr('/api/users', fetcher)



  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((user) => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          <Link href="/user/[id]" as={`/user/${user.id}`}>
            <a>{`User ${user.id}`}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

So my problem, when I get data from REST API and fetching it i dont appear HTML source code i appear only loading or any..
Why? How can i solve this?
Thank you.

*********SOLVED********

this is already stated in the next documentation. A structure as in the example should be used

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: `data` could be an empty array or undefined? Maybe `user` is undefined?

Comment: your Index function needs to wait for the Promise returned from `fetcher()` to resolve. Or `useSwr()` does; it's not clear because `useSwr()` is not posted or described.

Comment: This is a React component, so the `useSwr` hook is supposed (presumably) to handle state causing the `Index` function to be **automatically re-run** when there is data to populate `data` with. When `Index` is initially run it would be expected to be empty, but then the function should run again with data. There isn't enough information to tell why that isn't happening here. Looking at the value of `error` would be a good place to start! As would checking the developer tools console and Network tab for errors.

Comment: So what should I do  when I fetching data with map or any.. ?

Comment: i had problems with Swr, better you make your own hook with useEffect

Comment: @Suat — I said: "Looking at the value of error would be a good place to start! As would checking the developer tools console and Network tab for errors. "

Comment: This looks a lot like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66367790/1870780). As I mentioned there, the issue is most likely with one of the parent components that's not rendering something that it should. You'll need to provide additional details.

Comment: I solved this. I should use getServerSideProps thanks everyone!

Comment: Why does that solve the problem?